# Can I include characters such as "ã" and "ê" in UTF-8 encoded XML, or must it be UTF-16 encoded?

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

Can I include characters such as "ã" and "ê" in UTF-8 encoded XML, or must it be UTF-16 encoded?

Answer (score 7):

You can encode those characters in UTF-8.

The key is to keep the prolog (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`) and the actual file encoding consistent.

The whole point of UTF-8 is to be able to encode all the Unicode characters in a smaller footprint.  According to the source of all wisdom, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), utf-8 encodes each character point in 1 to 4 bytes, and is backwards compatible with ASCII

Comment: The "smaller footprint" doesn't apply to all characters: U+0800 to U+FFFF are larger in UTF-8 than in UTF-16.

Comment: Also notice that UTF-8 is the default encoding for XML, so if there is no prolog, the file must be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @dan04: but 75-90% of an XML file is tag garbage, so the smaller representation for ASCII outweighs any growth for the U+0800-U+FFFF range. :-)

Comment: @R.., Well, XML tags aren't *necessarily* in ASCII.

Answer (score 6):

All Unicode Transformation Format encodings can encode any character found in Unicode. The characters given are found in the Unicode standard.